# Visual Studio Online Build - Visual Studio SDK and Modellng SDK

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I have included [Visual Studio SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441.aspx) and [Modeling SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126259.aspx) in my project in order to build my T4 templates. It has been working fine until I wanted to set up the VSO Build, which gives me the following error:

> The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

However, I was unable to find any options or settings to import/include the mentioned SDKs into the build machine.

Comment: Are you using the hosted build service?

Comment: @DanielMann Yes I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSO Hosted build agent does not have Modeling SDK installed, refer to [Hosted pool](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/build/hosted-agent-pool) and [Hosted build controller](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/build/hosted-build-controller-vs) for details.

To build your solution, you need to [deploy your own build agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/agents/windows) and install the required SDK on it.

Comment: Well, that is sad. I was hoping to simply enable some optins.

Comment: @Santhos, Eddie is correct that you need to set up your own build server to connect to VSO. You can submit one feature request on the UserVoice site (https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).

Comment: I will see if it is easier to set up the build agent or remove the two T4 templates :)

Comment: @Vicky-MSFT, as you suggested, someone created a ticket for this feature on UserVoice (https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/15495060-include-modeling-sdk-for-visual-studio-on-the-host).  I recommend that anyone interested in that feature go there and vote for it.